# How do I fix the viewport of Cordova built app in iOS 7.1 when an input element is selected?

Tags: cordova, ios7, hybrid-mobile-app, ios7.1

In iOS 7.1, when any input field (text, select, etc) is being focused, the input control (like keyboard or drop list) slides up, and the entire screen is pushed up and the status bar overlaps the content.

In iOS 7.0, there is no such issue as the top of the canvas is always locked, so the windows size shrink when the input control appears from the bottom.

Screenshot of the problem in iOS 7.1:
[image]